# Instagram API: How can I automatically receive an access token in a Java application?

Tags: java, instagram, instagram-api

I am writing an application in Java which retrieves information from Instagram server by their API, accumulates it and builds a visualization map.

The problem is that I cannot automate the authentication process. The official Instagram API documentation states that:

> In order to receive an access_token, you must do the following:
>
> Direct the user to our authorization URL.
>
> If the user is not logged in, they will be asked to log in.
> The user will be asked if they would like to grant your application access to her Instagram data.
> The server will redirect the user in one of two ways that you choose

So it is a compulsory step for a user to login manually into his/her account. I believe that this is done in order to grant permissions to an app that uses Instagram API on behave of a user, for example, if it makes some posts in his/her account. However, I am not going to use any user's personal account. In fact I set up a separate account for my application and registered the app (I got client_id, client_secret and set the redirect_uri). So I want only to use those credentials in order to get updated access token and make some REST API posts to Instagram.

I make a GET request, receive back a login html page, parse it, insert my account credentials and after I make a POST request I receive the 400 code:

```
Sending 'GET' request to URL : instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=localhost&response_type=code

Response Code : 200
Extracting form data...

Sending 'POST' request to URL : instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIET_ID&redirect_uri=localhost&response_type=code
Request content:CONTENT&username=LOGIN&password=PASSWORD&=Log+in

Response Code : 302

Sending 'POST' request to URL : www.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=localhost&response_type=code
Request content:CLIENT_ID&username=LOGIN&password=PASSWORD&=Log+in

Response Code : 400
```

I don't understand why am I redirrected one more time. I am assuming that is because some security issues, maybe some hidden fields... How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

As I can understand from the requests, it uses the [OAuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) protocol which is common for Google, Twitter and more popular site authentication protocols.

Try an OAuth library such as: *[Google OAuth Client Library for Java](https://github.com/google/google-oauth-java-client)*

Comment: Thanks for the link! I'll try it out and report on the success soon